# Error When i Try to install any pkg with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

I wish some one can help me. When I try to install any pkg with pip, I get the following error:

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

---

I tried many solutions like upgrade the `setuptools` but it's not working.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the log file say? Try `pip install PACKAGE --log LOG_FILE` and paste log file here. Write log to /tmp or somewhere else where you know for sure that you have permission to write.

Comment: there is no log file :(

Comment: Not even if you add that `--log` parameter to your command

Comment: here is what in the log file ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score -2):

Update setup tools `pip install -U setuptools`  Or `pip3` if you're using Python3

Comment: it's giving me that the pkg is up to date and still have the error